# Tensorboard hangs on Pytorch Profile

Tags: pytorch, profiler

I'm trying to view the results from my torch.profiler.profile..

Here's my code snippet (minus the entire network that I was profiling in a train loop...)

```
    with SummaryWriter(tb_dir) as writer, open(logfn, "wt", encoding="utf-8") as logfp, \
        torch.profiler.profile(
            activities=[
                torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CPU,
                torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CUDA,
            ],
            schedule=torch.profiler.schedule(
                wait=1,
                warmup=1,
                active=2
            ),
            on_trace_ready=torch.profiler.tensorboard_trace_handler(profile_dir, worker_name="hmm")
        ) as profiler:
        while (args.max_epochs is None or epoch < args.max_epochs) and (args.max_time is None or total_elapsed < args.max_time):
            train(model, epoch, train_dataset, ema_node_loss, opt, sched, crit) # This is a function defined elsewhere that just does the training loop.
            # a whole bunch of other stuff deleted for brevity
            profiler.step()
```

And, it *does* write into my profile_dir these rather ginormous json files:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 binesh binesh 10049360679 Jun 20 19:40 hmm.1655768373559.pt.trace.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 binesh binesh 10094463514 Jun 20 20:54 hmm.1655772846630.pt.trace.json
```

Then, after installing the [tensorboard plugin](https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/tree/master/tb_plugin), I go to http://localhost:6006/ and I see it just constantly "loading"... I've left it running for more than an hour to no avail.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try loading it in `chrome://tracing`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by setting `with_stack=False`. Apparently, the interpreter did not like the relative paths that it was getting into my code, and this caused the loading to get hung up. I guess this means I can't step through the code with the profiler on, but that's not what I was looking to do.